# I want to be able to share a stored procedure and column of a table with a reader account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to share a view with a reader account and give them access to a stored procedure to sort the column. I am showing the query, text,start time and status of the query history in a particular database. I have given a few accounts the role that I want to give view access and usage access to this view and a stored procedure, I don't know how to set those grants.

For example the view definition:

```
CREATE SECURE View Student_queries_view
  comment='this' 
AS 
SELECT Query_id, query_text, start_time, EXECUTION_STATUS FROM "TEMP_DB"."PUBLIC"."TEMP_HISTORY"
```

Another example I have is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sorting()
   Returns Varchar
   Language javascript
   as
   $$
    var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: 
      `SELECT Query_id, query_text, start_time, execution_status FROM "TEMP_DB"."PUBLIC"."TEMP_HISTORY" Order by start_time;`
       } );
  return 'Done.';   
   $$;

Call Sorting(student_queries_view);
```

I have read the access control on stored procedures here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#privileges-on-stored-procedures

Any clue on the error of the Secure view and any direction on how to grant a stored procedure to just one role on the view I created?

My stored procedure returns an [object object], can I return a select statement?
[image]

Comment: Your error message says `'EXCUTION_STATUS'`, but your VIEW create SQL says `execution_status` and your Stored Procedure SQL say `excution_status`. Did you just spell it wrong in your actual view DDL and Procedure SPL?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I spelled it incorrectly. I also realize that my stored procedure does something different, let me update that as well.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you're simply trying to understand how to share a Secure View and Stored Procedure with a Snowflake `Reader Account`? Have you done any of the following: 

1) Create a Reader Account
2) Create a Share
3) Associate Share to Reader Account
4) Add database and database objects to Share
5) From Reader Account create a Database based on the share

IF you haven't done any of the following you need to read through this: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html#managing-reader-accounts